# Table storage design for querying with a value within a range

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, google-cloud-bigtable, nosql

I am looking at using a Table Storage, like Azure or Google or Apache HBase type for storing entities/rows but I could not find any help online for my usage pattern. It goes like this:

- Entity has an ID or key, say "UserId"
- Date value like "StartedUsingProduct"
- Date value like "StoppedUsingProduct"

The queries will mostly be of type **"At date T, find all users who were using the product"**. Note that the same UserId will have many (thousands) of start/stop pairs.

In the Azure case,
 - PartitionKey would be UserID
 - RowKey "StartedUsingProduct"
 but then I can't find a decent way to query without going through a full partition scan.

In the Google case, following their recommendation, 
 - key would be like "UserID_StartUsingProduct",
 and I get the same problem when I have to retrieve a substantial amount of rows and then filter out using the second property.

Has anyone some insights on how to attack this particular usage pattern?

Comment: This is fairly broad - no single "correct table arrangement. I suggest 1) you make this more specific - show the queries you're running, and the issues you run into and 2) separate your questions. Right now, you tagged two completely different cloud providers / table storage services.

Comment: I do not agree with you. Azure table storage and Google big table are essentially the same thing, with the slight difference that Azure has split the row key in two parts, and Google recommends a concatenation of the two parts into the single key. They are both NoSql, key-value stores, and queries are optimized when hitting directly a key or a range of keys. They can both have any number of columns, and these columns can change from one row to the other.

Comment: as for 1) show the queries, it is already there, in **bold**. That's the only query of concern right now.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you only get an update when a user "starts" or "stops" using the product? Do you not get a daily "ping" that the user is still using the product? So, e.g., if a user starts using the product on Jan 1, and stops on Dec 31, but on July 5, if you ask the question, it should be able to find the Jan 1 "start" marker and no existing stop marker, and hence conclude that this user is still using the product?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a very simple entity design considering just these three custom attributes:

1. UserId
2. Action - Would indicate either start or stop
3. DateTime

So when a user starts using the product, you insert an entity for that user with `Action = start` and `DateTime = current date/time`. Likewise when a user stops using the product, you insert an entity for that user with `Action = stop` and `DateTime = current date/time`.

**The pattern that you will have to use is store multiple records for a single activity**.

This is needed because you could either be querying on a date (like you mentioned above) or querying on a user e.g. tell me how many times this user has started/stopped using the product.

1st Entity will have `PartitionKey = UserId` and `RowKey = Current Date/Time`. You can store the current date/time in form of ticks converted to string using something like `DateTimeValue.Ticks.ToString("d20")`. This pattern will ensure that you will be able to query activity by the user. You would specify the query as `PartitionKey eq UserId` and you will get all the records for that user. If you're interested in getting the latest activities first, you could use reverse ticks in RowKey using something like `(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTimeValue.Ticks).ToString("d20")`. This will ensure that the latest records are prepended instead of appended.

2nd Entity will have `PartitionKey = DateTimeValue.Date` and `RowKey = UserId`. If you think that a user would start/stop using the software more than one time in a day, you would want to append the date time value in RowKey as well using something like `RowKey = UserId|DateTimeValue`. This will ensure that multiple start/stop activities for a user in a day can be logged without overwriting the previous activity for that user on that day. Now you can do a query on PartitionKey and that will tell you exactly what all users started/stopped using the product.